# How to traverse M*N grid in KDB

Tags: kdb

How to traverse m*n grid in Qlang, you can traverse up , down or diagonally.
to find how many possible ways end point can be reached.

Like Below :

> ```
>                   0
>                   |
>            ------- ------
>           |       |       |
>       ( 0 1)    (1 1)         (1 0) 
>          |         .          |
>    ------ -----            ------ -----
>   |            |   .      |            |
> ( 0 1)        (1 0)       ( 1 1)        (2 0)   
> .... 
> (2 2)        .....................   (2 2)
> ```

Comment: Question needs more info, a reproducible example, a starting point and/or a desired outcome

Comment: Added the tree traversal of it, mark's solution below helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it using `.z.s` to recursively call the initial function with different arguments and summing to give total number of paths.

```
f:{
  // When you reach a wall, there is only one way to corner so return valid path
  if[any 1=(x;y);:1];
  // Otherwise spawn 3 paths - one up, one right and one diagonally
  :.z.s[x-1;y] + .z.s[x;y-1] + .z.s[x-1;y-1] 
}

q)f[2;2]
3
q)f[2;3]
5
q)f[3;3]
13
```

If you are travelling along the edges and not the squares you can change the first line to:

```
if[any 0=(x;y);:1];
```

A closed form solution is just finding the [Delannoy Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number), which could be implemented something like this when you are travelling along edges.

```
d:{
  k:1+min(x;y);
  f:{prd 1+til x};
  comb:{[f;m;n] f[m] div f[n]*f[m-n]}[f];
  (sum/) (2 xexp til k) * prd (x;y) comb/:\: til k
 }

q)d[3;3]
63f
```

This is much quicker for larger boards as I think the complexity of the first solution is O(3^m+n) while the complexity of the second is O(m*n)

```
q)\t f[7;7]
13
q)\t f[10;10]
1924
q)\t d[7;7]
0
q)\t d[100;100]
1
```